# How to fix Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found?

Tags: php, solr, centos6

I am trying to run to use the SolrClient [PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) but I am unable to do so successfully. I did everything in [this](https://www.cocking.com/2015/03/30/apache-solr-5-0-install-on-centos-7/) tutorial. But I keep getting the following error every time I try to create an object of the SolrClient class:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient' not found in /...
```

Server running:

1. CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 standard
2. WHM 11.52.0 (build 23)

Apache Solr:

```
solr-spec    5.3.1
solr-impl    5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:15
lucene-spec  5.3.1
lucene-impl  5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09
```

JVM: `Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (1.8.0_65 25.65-b01)`

Installed required extensions:

1. libxml2
2. curl

Comment: Have you installed the extensions for SolrClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by going to the WHM cpanel >> Software >> Module Installers >> PHP Pecl Manager

Then I searched for Solr then clicked install.

You might need to install curl-devel, pcre-devel before you install Solr module like so:

```
yum install curl-devel
yum install pcre-devel
```